# What should be the kafka serde configuration when we use kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are using a JDBC source connector to sync data from a table to a topic (call this Topic 1) in Kafka. As we know this captures only inserts and updates, we have added a trigger to capture deletes. This trigger captures the deleted record and writes to a new table which gets synced to another Kafka topic (call this Topic 2).

We have configured the JDBC source connector to use AvroConverter.

Now we have written a Kafka streams logic that consumes data from this Topic 2 and publishes to Topic 1. My question is what should be the serializer and deserializer configuration for the Kafka streams logic? Is it ok to use KafkaAvroSerializer and KafkaAvroDeserializer?

I was going through the AvroConverter code (https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroConverter.java) to see if I can get some ideas. I was navigating the Github code for quite some time. I was not able to conclude whether using KafkaAvoSerializer and KafkaAvroDeserializer is the right side in Kafka streams logic. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Why does your JDBC connector only capture inserts and updates?

**EDITED:** We use <strike>[Confluent JDBC source connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html)</strike> [SQL Server Debezium Connector](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html) and it performs well even on deletes. Pay attention to [query modes](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html#incremental-query-modes) specifically.

Maybe try switching to this connector and you might end up with one problem solved, having only one stream containing all the relevant events.

Comment: Please read this. https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc/. You will find this sentence - The JDBC Connector cannot fetch deleted rows. Because, how do you query for data that doesn’t exist?

Comment: Thanks. Now I see, that I linked correctly, but I accidentally switched JDBC and SQL Server connector.

Comment: I edited the answer to really represent what I meant. Sorry fer deceiving answer and thanks for correction.

Comment: No problem Zajo. Debezium connector involves licensing cost for Oracle/SQL Server. So, we have ruled out this option.